# Folder hierarchy gets lost after extracting

Tags: linux, bash, unzip

I have zipped file that contains multiple files and folders:

```
-$PlcLogic$/Application/Application.app 
-$PlcLogic$/Application/Application.crc
-$PlcLogic$/meta.info
```

After extracting with unzip on bash, Linux throws away the folder hierarchy and
creates a simple file without keeping the folder structure prior unzipping.

Output from ls -l after unzipping is:

```
-$PlcLogic$\Application\Application.app
-$PlcLogic$\Application\Application.crc
-$PlcLogic$\meta.info
```

The problem are the $'s which we are not able to change as it gets created from a different software.
Any idea how to keep the folder hierarchy here?

Comment: Can you add more detail to your question please? I suspect you have a zip file that uses winows path separators `\`, but that isn't 100% clear. Run `unzip -l` on the zip file to show us what exactly if in it. Also, for the output from unzipping, run `find` to show us the output directory hierarchy. Finally, what program did you use to create the zip file (include the command line of possible).

Comment: Unzip -l outputs me the same as it actually is after unzipping:

Archive:  backup.zip
  Length      Date    Time    Name
---------  ---------- -----   ----
      200  2020-05-04 12:16   meta.info
   355664  2020-05-04 12:16   $PlcLogic$\Application\Application.app
       20  2020-05-04 12:16   $PlcLogic$\Application\Application.crc
---------                     -------
   355884                     3 files

find gives me too many results for here to show.

I used codesys and created a backup of my project.

Thanks

Comment: You have an invalid zip file that is using windows path separators. To fix see https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/166159/convert-a-windows-created-zip-to-linux-internal-paths-issue  and https://superuser.com/questions/544786/unrar-creating-files-with-backslashes-in-names-instead-of-proper-directory-hiera/1328762#1328762

Comment: Thanks, that actually helped!